# java code to store milliseconds into an array

Tags: java

I have a table in which I've assigned burst time for each of machines in the form of `time` type in second for eg: 00:00:03, 00:00:02 etc.

I have a `JAVA` code that retrieves these burst times from the database and store it in a list and then convert each burst time into "milliseconds" type.

```
ArrayList<String>list22=new ArrayList<String>();
ResultSet rs = stmt1
        .executeQuery("SELECT burst_time FROM virtual_machine WHERE VM_id <= 4");

while (rs.next()) {
    list22.add(rs.getString("burst_time"));
}

String tempStamp = list22.get(0);
int i;

for(i=0;i<=list22.size()-1;i++){
    System.out.println(list22.get(i));
}

for(String startstamp : list22){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    java.util.Date d = null;
    try
    {
        d =  formatter.parse(startstamp);}
    catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    long qtm= d.getTime();
    System.out.println(qtm);
}
```

This gives me the following result:

```
00:00:03
00:00:02
00:00:02
00:00:03
3000
2000
2000
3000
```

Now I need to store those milliseconds values in an array `bur[]` and use it in the program so that the corresponding machines should run for the assigned time which is stored in the array.

And can u please tell me whether I'm going through the right path in case of storing the milliseconds in array and giving it to the machines.

Comment: One minor point - what is the point of using `TimeZone` when you process time duration only?

Comment: P.S. It feels like you are doing something (relatively) complicated to achieve a simple result.

Comment: What SQL type is column "burst_time" in your database?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this storing in the first place, perhaps stating the original aim would help us advising...

Comment: @GermannArlington Using the timezone UTC is very important to avoid wrong calculations (due to lack of duration type in old JDK). The OP "misuses" `SimpleDateFormat` to calculate a duration relative to a fixed point (1970-01-01T00:00Z).

Comment: @MenoHochschild Can you suggest a better option than using `SimpleDateFormat`? And I still don't see how the `TimeZone` will affect anything...

Comment: @GermannArlington About timezone, using the default timezone is dangerous, just try "Europe/London" and you see what I mean.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Thanks, it never occurred to me before - I never really had to deal with such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Following solution is nearly identical to the [answer of @nikis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22865766/642706), but preserves the important timezone setting. Otherwise users will get a surprising experience if this code runs in UK (Europe/London) because in year 1970 there was summer time - resulting in duration longs with one full hour too much:

```
 long[] bur = new long[list22.size()];

 for(int i=0; i < list22.size(); i++) {
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

     // important, but avoid deprecated Etc/GMT-notation
     formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

     try
     {
         java.util.Date d = formatter.parse(list22.get(i));
         long qtm= d.getTime();
         bur[i] = qtm;
         System.out.println(qtm);
     } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
         System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

Hereby I have presented a workaround for an unsupported handling of durations in JDK pre 8. The truth is that `SimpleDateFormat` is designed to parse points in time, but not durations. Therefore it is so important to have a fixed starting point which never changes, hence the choice of UTC time zone and the reference point 1970-01-01T00:00:00,000Z (elapsed milliseconds since UNIX epoch).

JodaTime offers a specialized `PeriodFormatter` which really yields a `org.joda.time.Period`. Else it is possible to write your own specialized string parser (by help of substring(), indexOf() etc.) to factor out the integer parts and then to use `Integer.valueOf(String)` and then to calculate a long using this simple formula: `(hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + second) * 1000`.

Comment: thank you so much for the help nd explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code to avoid `NPE` and also added `bur[]` array:

```
 ArrayList<String>list22=new ArrayList<String>();
 ResultSet rs = stmt1
            .executeQuery("SELECT burst_time FROM virtual_machine WHERE VM_id <= 4");

 while (rs.next()) {
     list22.add(rs.getString("burst_time"));
 }

 for(int i=0;i<list22.size();i++){
     System.out.println(list22.get(i));
 }

 long[] bur = new long[list22.size()];

 for(int i=0;i<list22.size();i++){
     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
     try
     {
         java.util.Date d = formatter.parse(list22.get(i));
         long qtm= d.getTime();
         bur[i] = qtm;
         System.out.println(qtm);
     } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
         System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int bur[] = new int[list22.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < list22.size(); i++) {
    String timeStamp = list22.get(i);
    String s, m, h, split;
    split = timeStamp.split(":");
    h = split[0];
    m = split[1];
    s = split[2];
    bur[i] = Integer.parseInt(s) * 1000 + Integer.parseInt(m) * 60000 + Integer.parseInt(h) * 3600000;
}
```

This solution doesn't use any date objects, since you won't need them in your case, if I'm not totally on the wrong way ;-)

Comment: what if the time will be `00:01:03`?

Comment: A hand-written parser is fine because JDK does not directly support duration calculations, but there is one error: You should use 3600000 instead of 1440000. And you meant String, not string?

Comment: @MenoHochschild: All right, didn't execute it, just typed down, thx!